# how to access input element in a polymer web-component

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I've managed to setup a simple registration form with Polymer:

```
<polymer-element name="app-registration">

    <template>
        <style>
            ...
        </style>
        <section>
            <paper-input class="username" .... ></paper-input>
            <paper-input class="password" .... ></paper-input>
            <paper-button label="Submit" on-tap="{{handleSubmit}}"></paper-button>
        </section>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            handleSubmit: function (event, detail, sender) {
                alert(this.querySelector('.username').value);
            }
        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

It works fine, however, within the `handleSubmit` callback I'm not able to query the values from the other input fields. Whatever I query `paper-input` or by classname I receive `null`. Any suggestion how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those elements are in your shadow dom, so you need `this.shadowRoot`. `this.querySelector()` will give you light dom nodes.

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.username').value
```

Better yet, would be to add an id:

```
<section id="container">
  <paper-input class="username" .... ></paper-input>
  ...
</section>
```

and use node finding: `this.$.container.querySelector('.username').value`.

Comment: Alternatively, since there's only one of each of those fields, set `id="username"` instead of `class="username"` (ditto for `password`). Then you could write `this.$.username.value`, without needing `querySelector()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was already available in 0.5, but in 1.0 you can do

```
this.$$(selector)
```

your example:

```
this.$$('.username').value
```

-> same but shorter, and works on dynamically created nodes

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#work-with-local-dom

Comment: Use `id="foo"` and `this.$.foo` when there is no dom repeat or dom if. This is more efficient as it uses a static map and does not query the dom.